# Get data from another model cakephp 3.5

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have table `questions` which contains `id`, `questions` and `marks`. Then, I have table `quizzes` which contains `id` and `quiz_name`. I created bridge table named `question_quizzes` which contains `id` from `quiz` table and `id` from `question` table. How can I display all of the data (`id`, `questions`, `marks`) in `questions` table into add form of `question_quizzes`?

EDIT:

This is existingQuestion function inside questionQuizzes controller. In existingQuestion function, I want to display all of the questions table

```
 class QuestionQuizzesController extends AppController
   public function existingQuestion()
  {
    $query = $questionQuizzes->find('all')->contain('Questions');
    foreach ($query as $questionQuizzes) {
        echo $questionQuiz->question->id;
    }
}
```

This is questionQuizzesTable

```
class QuestionQuizzesTable extends Table
{


/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */

 var $name = 'QuestionQuizzes';

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('question_quizzes');

    $this->belongsTo('Quizzes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'quiz_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Questions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
 * application integrity.
 *
 * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
 * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
 */
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['quiz_id'], 'Quizzes'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['question_id'], 'Questions'));

    return $rules;
}
}
```

I have edited my coding but still there is an error "Call to a member function find() on null". Can anybody help me?? I'm stucked

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: I want to display all of the data in questions table into add form of question_quizzes. So, I should put the operations query in question controller or question_quizzes controller?

Comment: I have edited this post

Comment: Usually, we don't create a form for the pivot table. It isn't a real entity and it exists only to create a many-to-many relationship with another entity.

Comment: I have edited my coding and still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

When you write `$query = $questionQuizzes->find()`, you have not declared `$questionQuizzes` anywhere. Variables don't just spring fully-formed into being. Hence, it's null, and you are trying to call a function on it. This should all have been fairly self-evident from the error message you got, surely it directed you right to the line in question? (There are snippets of code in the link @urfusion provided that just reference `$articles`, but those are shown without context and assume that you have created the variable in advance.)

The fix would be to use `$this->questionQuizzes->find()`. The `questionQuizzes` member of `$this` should have been initialized by Cake thanks to what you're doing in your initialize function. The relevant part of the manual would be the section on the [Query Builder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html).

Note that Cake conventions would have you name your table questions_quizzes, not question_quizzes; both parts are plural. Or quizzes_questions would work too, and makes more sense to me personally (it tracks the quizzes' questions, after all). There's nothing wrong with the name you've chosen, but examples might fit themselves into your code more easily if you follow the conventions more completely.